# Accessing instance variable when defined in global in controller ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here I declare instance variable as global. In the input statement, I'm not getting output `"home/abc.txt"`. What is the syntax to access instance variable inputs?

```
class AbcController
  @filename = 'home/abc.txt'  

  def querypass
    puts @filename
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declared like that, `@filename` asssignment is run in context of the class and is sth called class instance variable. `querypass` method is defined on class instance and has no access to it. Probably what you want to do is:

```
class AbcController

  def initialize 
    @filename = 'home/abc.txt'
  end

  def querypass
    puts @filename
  end

  ...
end
```

In this case each instance will have its own copy of the variable and each of them will start with same initial value. However, if you really want to have a single variable for the whole class, you can do:

```
class AbcController
  class << self
    attr_accessor :filename  # or attr_reader
  end
  @filename = 'home/abc.txt'  

  def querypass
    puts self.class.filename
  end

  ...
end
```

Or if you don't want to create any class setter or reader:

```
class AbcController
  @filename = 'home/abc.txt'  

  def querypass
    puts self.class.instance_variable_get(:@filename)
  end

  ...
end
```